# What is the index.Rmd file in the base directory intended for?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, hugo, blogdown

I have believed that the file `index.Rmd` is called when the building procedure begins, so I add several package installation checking there. Unfortunately, the code chunks in the `index.Rmd` won't execute at all.

And to my surprise, the site will be normally built even after I deleted `index.Rmd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `index.Rmd` under the root directory of a **blogdown** website won't be compiled. Only its `site` field in the YAML metadata is read (if exists) by the RStudio IDE to obtain the site generator. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/rstudio-ide.html (this section is about **bookdown**, but the idea is the same for **blogdown**).

It is totally safe to remove `index.Rmd` if you don't need to use the `Build` button in RStudio (typically you won't need to).